# Selection appropriate STL container for logging Data

Tags: c++, stl

I require logging and filtering mechanism in my client server application.where client may request log data based on certain parameter.

log will have MACID,date and time,command type and direction as field.

server can filter log data based on these parameter as well.
size of the the log is 10 mb afterwards the log will be override the message from beginning.

My approach is I will log data in to file as well in the STL container as **"in memory"** so that when the client request data server will filter the log data  based on any criteria

So the process is server will first do the sorting on particular criteria on vector<> and then filter it using binary search.

I am planning to use vector as STL container for in memory logging data.

I am bit confused whether vector will appropriate on this situation or not.

since size of the data can max upto 10 mb in vector.
my question whether vector is fare enough for this case or not ?

Comment: I am still not clear that, if you are logging already on file then why do you need logging into `vector` also ? Does your code require to read `vector` also ?

Comment: I need to store log info in the vector to filter it once user request the log data based on above mentioned parameter.its client server program where server logs data and client request it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go with a deque, double ended queue. It's like a vector but you can add/remove elements from both ends.

Comment: Why do you want to add/remove elements at the beginning in this case?

Comment: element need to be removed once 10 mb size is reached.last added message will be removed if the limit is reached.

Comment: Events get added at one end and removed at the other.

You can accomplish the same thing with a vector and a pointer that tells you where to overwrite old events, but the deque just does that for you.

Comment: If you really want this custom in-memory filtering, then sure. But I'd first check if reports from an already written logging library are sufficient. Maybe you don't really need to keep this cache.

Answer (score 1):

I would first state that I would use a logging library since there are many and I assure you they will do a better job ([log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html) for ex). If you insist on doing this your yourself A vector is an appropriate mechanism but you will have to manually sort the data biased upon user requests. One other idea is to use sqllite and let it manage storing sorting and filtering your data.

Comment: Did you mean log4cxx? The log4cpp library seems to have stopped development in 2007.

Comment: Yes. I couldn't remember the actual ones name but log4cxx is the apache project.

Comment: I am using log4cxx but only for logging info in the file.does log4cxx support filtering.

Answer (score 0):

The actual response will depend a lot on the usage pattern and interface. If you are using a graphical UI, then chances are that there is already a widget that implements that feature to some extent (ability to sort by different columns, and even filter). If you really want to implement this outside of the UI, then it will depend on the usage pattern, will the user want a particular view more than others? does she need only filtering, or also sorting?

If there is one view of the data that will be used in most cases, and you only need to show a different order a few times, I would keep an `std::vector` or `std::deque` of the elements, and filter out with `remove_copy_if` when needed. If a different sort is required, I would *copy* and sort the copy, to avoid having to re-sort back to time based to continue adding elements to the log. Beware if you the application keeps pushing data that you will need to update the *copy* with the new elements in place (or provide a fixed view and rerun the operation periodically).

If there is no particular view that occurs much more often than the rest, of if you don't want to go through the pain of implementing the above, take a look a boost multi index containers. They keep synchronized views of the same data with different criteria. That will probably be the most efficient in this last case, and even if it might be less efficient in the general case of a dominating view, it might make things simpler, so it could still be worth it.